# Animating bootstrap dropdown menu on click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
$('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(250).slideDown();
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(100).slideUp()
});
```

With mouseover works fine but I need to open after clicked. If I replace **.hover** with **.click** when the dropdown is clicked it opens and close real quick.

Is it possible to do it the traditional way with bootstrap, to open when clicked and to close when mouseout or click anywhere else? Any help. Thanks.

Comment: can you post your relevant html too?

Comment: There we go: http://jsbin.com/oxarim/1/edit

Comment: HI, i just tried a version see if this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 9):

You can use CSS3 transitions:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
}

.open .dropdown-menu {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Check browser support on http://caniuse.com/css-transitions

Comment: I don't know you, but I love you.

Answer (score 9):

In BootStrap 3, you can use dropdown events :

```
       // ADD SLIDEDOWN ANIMATION TO DROPDOWN //
        $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown();
        });

        // ADD SLIDEUP ANIMATION TO DROPDOWN //
        $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp();
        });
```

Answer (score 5):

Yokomizor's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245923/animating-bootstrap-dropdown-menu-on-click/22827976#22827976) on using CSS transitions is a nice idea, but in his code below:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
}
.open .dropdown-menu {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

What he ends up doing is that he is only making the dropdown invisible only, but in actual fact the things on the dropdown is still there, just that you can't see it. A better way is:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-out;
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
    transform-origin: top;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
}
.open .dropdown-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform-origin: top;
}
```

In this case, it also creates a nice (sort of) slide down and up animation.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/CZX123/asqv5pxt/)

Comment: why did you use rotateX() instead of scaleY() ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, see if this is what you are looking for. Click to open dropdown, mouse out to hide it. http://jsbin.com/ibovag/1/

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('mouseover', function(){
  $(this).on('mouseleave',hideDropdown);
});
function hideDropdown(e)
{
  $(this).closest('.open').removeClass('open');
  $(this).off('mouseleave');
 }
```

Comment: What Bootstrap does out of the box is to open dropdown after clicked and close when click anywhere else which is perfect for me but what I've been trying to figure out is how to add some animation when the dropdown opens and closes. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, but your original issue way to make it close on mouse out right? or did i get it wrong? By the way you should be able to provide animation but will have to make the dropdown open manual.

Comment: One more thing. When you click any of the links without mouseovering the dropdown menus they will stay open.

Answer (score 0):

You can use slideToggle from JQuery!

http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

like this:

```
$('.navbar .dropdown').click(function() {
  $('.dropdown-menu', this).slideToggle(250);
});
```

Comment: How would you go about closing all other dropdowns when you open another one? I tried adding $('.dropdown-menu').siblings().slideUp; at the end of the function, and it didn't work.

Comment: @kris-hunt, I've tested it on Bootstrap 3 and it does not work. I think you should use psl anwser or CSS3 transitions. I will delete this answer after you check this comment.

Answer (score 0):

i have used this on hover and is working fine, here is the fiddle for this

http://jsfiddle.net/html5beginners/rtqnxrLd/6/embedded/result/

```
body {
  background: #333;
  width: 98% !important;
}
.DonateUs{
    width: 200px;
height: 60px;
background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #16A085;
color: #fff;
Padding: 13px 56px;
font-size: 20px;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px #023d31;
float:right
text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #023d31;font-family: oswald;
}
.navbar-x {
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-x .nav {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-x .nav:hover.nav-pills > li.active > a, .navbar-x .nav:focus.nav-pills > li.active > a {
  color: #eee;
}

.navbar-x .nav:hover.nav-pills > li.active > a:hover, .navbar-x .nav:hover.nav-pills > li.active > a:focus, .navbar-x .nav:focus.nav-pills > li.active > a:hover, .navbar-x .nav:focus.nav-pills > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #FFCB00;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.navbar-x .nav > li > a {
  width: 94px;
  color: #eee;
  transition: color 0.42s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-x .nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-x .nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #FFCB00;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.navbar-x .nav > li.active > a {
  color: #FFCB00;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.navbar-x .nav > li.bottom-bar {
  transition: left 0.42s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 90px;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ebbf00;
}

.navbar-x .nav > li:nth-child(1).active ~ .bottom-bar {
  left: 0px;
}

.navbar-x .nav > li:nth-child(1):hover ~ .bottom-bar, .navbar-x .nav > li:nth-child(1):focus ~ .bottom-bar {
  left: 0px !important;
}

.navbar-x .nav > li:nth-child(2).active ~ .bottom-bar {
  left: 100px;
}

.navbar-x .nav > li:nth-child(2):hover ~ .bottom-bar, .navbar-x .nav > li:nth-child(2):focus ~ .bottom-bar {
  left: 100px !important;
}

.navbar-x .nav > li:nth-child(3).active ~ .bottom-bar {
  left: 200px;
}

.navbar-x .nav > li:nth-child(3):hover ~ .bottom-bar, .navbar-x .nav > li:nth-child(3):focus ~ .bottom-bar {
  left: 200px !important;
}

.navbar-x .nav > li:nth-child(4).active ~ .bottom-bar {
  left: 300px;
}

.navbar-x .nav > li:nth-child(4):hover ~ .bottom-bar, .navbar-x .nav > li:nth-child(4):focus ~ .bottom-bar {
  left: 300px !important;
}

.navbar-x .nav > li:nth-child(5).active ~ .bottom-bar {
  left: 400px;
}

.navbar-x .nav > li:nth-child(5):hover ~ .bottom-bar, .navbar-x .nav > li:nth-child(5):focus ~ .bottom-bar {
  left: 400px !important;
}

.about {
  margin: 70px auto 40px;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 360px;
  font: 10px/18px 'Lucida Grande', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #bbb;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background: #383838;
  background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.8);
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.about a {
  color: #eee;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.1s;
  -o-transition: background 0.1s;
  transition: background 0.1s;
}

.about a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #555;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}

.about-links {
  height: 30px;
}

.about-links > a {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.about-author {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.about-author > a {
  padding: 1px 3px;
  margin: 0 -1px;
}

.logo-html5beginners {
  margin: -12px 0 0 0px;
  width: 39%;
}
```

Comment: Strange link.  Please, fix that